# How do you remove the vertical distance between references in lyx?

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

Using LyX, a BibTeX file and the `unsrt` bibliography style. The program automatically leaves an empty line between each reference, wasting lots of space in the process!

Is there any way to force LyX to leave no vertical gaps between references?

Here is a LaTeX MWE (more or less generated by LyX) showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{testlyx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the sample file "testlyx.bib":

```
@ARTICLE{authorA,
  author = {AuthorA},
  title = {This is the title A},
  journal = {journal A},
  year = {1993},
  volume = {47},
  pages = {58--61},
  month = {Feb}
}

@ARTICLE{authorB,
  author = {AuthorB},
  title = {That is the title B},
  journal = {journal A},
  year = {1994},
  volume = {50},
  pages = {53--79},
  month = {May}
}
```

Comment: Do you use a citation management package, such as `cite`, `natbib`, or `harvard`, as well? Depending on which package is used, different commands are available to reduce the spacing between entries in the bibliography.

Comment: In `Document Settings->Bibliography`, my citation style is set to `Default(numerical)`. If that answers the question...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a `lyx` specialist, and thus don't know how to translate lyx's information (`Default(numerical)`) into a series of LaTeX commands that underlie this information. :-( Hopefully, someone else can jump in and help you out.

Comment: I doubt if Lyx is to be blamed. Lyx has no unique reference management utilities and it uses standard LaTeX packages for dealing with references (bibtex, natbib, biblatex). You should prob. tweak the Bibtex options to solve that (unfortunately I use biblatex so I can't help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between items is defined by the article class to be 4pt; you can change it by patching the `\thebibliography` command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{authorA,
  author = {AuthorA},
  title = {This is the title A},
  journal = {journal A},
  year = {1993},
  volume = {47},
  pages = {58--61},
  month = {Feb}
}

@ARTICLE{authorB,
  author = {AuthorB},
  title = {That is the title B},
  journal = {journal A},
  year = {1994},
  volume = {50},
  pages = {53--79},
  month = {May}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

%%% Start of code to add %%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\thebibliography
 {\labelsep}
 {\labelsep\itemsep=0pt\relax}
 {}
 {\typeout{Couldn't patch the command}}
 %%% End of code to add %%%

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the `filecontents` environment is just for convenience in making a self contained example. The code you should add is marked in the example. How you can do it in LyX is beyond my knowledge.

[image]

If the normal spacing between lines is wanted, then a slight change will do:

```
%%% Start of code to add %%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\thebibliography
 {\labelsep}
 {\labelsep\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\relax}
 {}
 {\typeout{Couldn't patch the command}}
 %%% End of code to add %%%
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Good, spacing is reduced. If the "usual" one line spacing is required it seems that changing `\itemsep=0pt` to `\itemsep=-4pt` does the further reduction... Anyway, for LyX, just copy and paste the code between `%%% Start...` and `%%% End...` into the LaTeX Preamble under "Document > Settings...".

Comment: @e-birk I've added also how to remove the additional spacing (it's due to `\parsep`).

Comment: Easy, worked great!

Comment: Why it is not working in my report?

Comment: @DeepeshPatel It's difficult to say. Please, open a new question referring to this one, with a minimal example showing failure.