# Reduce spacing between citations with unsrt bibliography style

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib

I am using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with LaTeX (using TeXShop on a Mac) in a document with `\documentclass{article}` and I find that my bibliography is taking up a lot of space because there is a blank line between every bibliographic entry.

How can I most easily remove these blank lines between entries?  Do I have to use a custom .bst file?

Placing the `\bibliography` command in a `singlespacing` environment does not help, and changing the value of `parskip` there doesn't do anything.

My problem is similar to the one [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104386/how-do-you-remove-the-vertical-distance-between-references-in-lyx), except the solution posted there isn't working for me.

Comment: the spacing between bib items is almost always defined as part of the definition of `thebibliography` in the document class you're using.  so modification of that definition is what is likely required.  that *is* mentioned in the question you cited.

Comment: Are you using the `setspace` package and doublespacing the document? If so, please add a minimal example; of course my code in the linked question *does* work. `;-)`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes I tried the patch to `\thebibliography` as given in the linked question/answer, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.  Not sure if I'm missing something, but I'm implementing it as in the example.

Comment: @egreg Yes I did use the `setspace` package when I attempted to use the `singlespacing` environment.  The whole document is **not**  set to `doublespacing` (everything else is single-spaced).

Answer (score 6):

OK I think I figured out my own question:

The solution I linked to originally wasn't working for me because I was implementing `\usepackage{natbib}` in my preamble (had pasted over a set of packages from another file and didn't realize this was in there).  If I comment out the `natbib` package, then the referenced patch to `\thebibliography` does work.

However, I can easily accomplish what I want while still using the `natbib` package.  This is done by adding `\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}` in the preamble.  Note that the separation can be any desired value.  I find `0pt` to be too condensed and `2pt` or `4pt` looks fairly pleasing.

Credit to [this site](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-compactbib) for the tip.

I hope this helps someone else!